# Change Object in vue3 typeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

My original object is as follows (Object name is **runOverview**). I want to remove bold fields version, inputs, loads, products and project_name.

> {
> "**version**": "1",
> "**inputs**": [
> {
> "name": "input1",
> "value": "1,827"
> },
> {
> "name": "input2",
> "value": "310"
> }
> ],
> "**loads**": [
> {
> "name": "loads1",
> "value": "440"
> },
> {
> "name": "loads2",
> "value": "220"
> },
> {
> "name": "loads3",
> "value": "46"
> }
> ],
> "**products**": [
> {
> "name": "products1",
> "value": "15,000"
> },
> {
> "name": "products3",
> "value": "4.8"
> }
> ],
> "**project_name**": "Test"
> }

I want to change runOverview object as bellow (expected output).

> 

```
   {{
      "name": "input1",
      "value": "1,827"
    },
    {
      "name": "input2",
      "value": "310"
    },
    {
      "name": "loads1",
      "value": "440"
    },
    {
      "name": "loads2",
      "value": "220"
    },
    {
      "name": "loads3",
      "value": "46"
    },
    {
      "name": "products1",
      "value": "15,000"
    },
    {
      "name": "products3",
      "value": "4.8"
    }}
```

I've tried as follows

```js
const overviewDetails = computed(() => {
  const overviewArr = [];
    for ( var newdata in runOverview.value) {
      overviewArr.push(newdata)
    }
  return overviewArr
});
```

**Please help me to create new object array with only necessary properties**

Comment: Your expected output is not possible due to a syntax error

Comment: I just want to use names and values in new object, Is there way to do it? Thanks @TachibanaShin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very powerful it will merge any property whose value is an array. I believe this is what you want:

```js
// </script><script type="module">
import { ref, computed } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.runtime.esm-browser.js"

const runOverview = ref({ "version": "1", "inputs": [ { "name": "input1", "value": "1,827" }, { "name": "input2", "value": "310" } ], "loads": [ { "name": "loads1", "value": "440" }, { "name": "loads2", "value": "220" }, { "name": "loads3", "value": "46" } ], "products": [ { "name": "products1", "value": "15,000" }, { "name": "products3", "value": "4.8" } ], "project_name": "Test" })

const overviewDetails = computed(() => {
  return Object.values(runOverview.value).reduce((r, item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) r.push(...item)

    return r
  }, [])
})

console.log(overviewDetails.value)
```

Comment: Do you know how to add one more element at end of this overviewDetails array? Ex: { name:"test1", value:"100"} ?

Comment: please declare `const arr = Object.values...; arr.push(<item>); return arr`

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = []
Object.values(runOverview).forEach(item => {
        if(Array.isArray(item)) {
            arr.push(...item)
        }
    })
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `map` methods. Try this:

```html
<script type="module">
import { ref, computed } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.runtime.esm-browser.js"

const runOverview = ref({version:"1",inputs:[{name:"input1",value:"1,827"},{name:"input2",value:"310"},],loads:[{name:"loads1",value:"440"},{name:"loads2",value:"220"},{name:"loads3",value:"46"},],products:[{name:"products1",value:"15,000"},{name:"products3",value:"4.8"},],project_name:"Test"});

 const overviewDetails = computed(() =>
  ["inputs", "loads", "products"].reduce(
    (acc, key) =>
      acc.concat(
        runOverview.value[key].map((item) => ({
          name: item.name,
          value: item.value,
        }))
      ),
    []
  )
);
console.log(overviewDetails.value)

</script>
```

Comment: There is issue "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Ref<PlainRunOverview>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Ref<PlainRunOverview>'" @protob

Comment: I added the working snippet.